# PHP -- Get item in array by numerical index stored in a variable?

Tags: php, mysqli, indexing

I have a database, and I'm querying it to get all rows.  Then, I get a specific record identified by a variable called `id` which is from `somepage.php?id=aninteger`

For some reason, I can't figure out how to get the result which is number `id` in the database.  (It starts at 0).

Here is my code:

```
<?php
        $connection = mysqli_connect("host","user","password","database");
        $id = $_POST['id'];

        $result = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM Scavenger");
        $resultIDArray = array();
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) { 
            array_push($resultIDArray, $row['ID']);
        }
        $resultQArray = array();
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
            array_push($resultQArray, $row['Key']);
        }
        $resultAArray = array();
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
            array_push($resultAArray, $row['Answer']);
        }
        echo "<p>BlahBlah<br>BlahBlah<br><br><br>".$resultQArray[(int) $id]."<br><br></p>";
        echo "<form action='checkAnswer.php' method='post'><input type='text' name='Answer' id='Answer'><input type='submit' value='Submit'></form>";
?>
```

I know there is something wrong with `$resultQArray[(int) $id]`, but for the life of me I can't seem to figure out what.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are walking all of your query results in your first where loop  so all of the subsequent loops are failing the condition check the first time through .... try doing all of your work the first time through.

```
    $connection = mysqli_connect("host","user","password","database");
    $id = $_POST['id'];

    $result = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM Scavenger");
    $resultIDArray = array()
    $resultQArray = array();
    $resultAArray = array();
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        array_push($resultIDArray, $row['ID']);
        array_push($resultQArray, $row['Key']);
        array_push($resultAArray, $row['Answer']);
    }
    echo "<p>BlahBlah<br>BlahBlah<br><br><br>".$resultQArray[(int) $id]."<br><br></p>";
    echo "<form action='checkAnswer.php' method='post'><input type='text' name='Answer' id='Answer'><input type='submit' value='Submit'></form>";
```

?>